# Add filter on ALV list - "exclude from selection" is not available

Tags: abap

I use function module "REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY_LVC" to output an internal table to the enduser. I want to enable the user to filter this list. Therefore the function "Set filter" could be used, unfortunately the option "exclude from selection" (red traffic light) is not available :-( Is it possible to give access to this option?

[image]

Comment: Other than using the second/or third tab "Exclude Single Values" - please add a minimal example (code!)  to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see the forest for the trees :-)[image]

Comment: Mark this as answer if it is.